# Add Custom Meta tag

Tags: magento2, meta-tags

hi i want to know is it possible to show a custom meta tag here i have created an attribute and assigned to the seo group and i want this value to be visible under meta tag for the current product
[image]

[image]

**default_head_blocks.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
            <meta property="og:type" content="product" />
            </head>
       <body>
           <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
                <block class="Test\Meta\Block\Meta" name="custom_meta" template="Test_Meta::custom_meta.phtml"/>
            </referenceBlock>
       </body> 
    

</page>
```

phtml file

```
<?php
$productCollection = $block->getProductCollection();
foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
    print_r($product->getData());     
    echo "<br>";

    $attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('miscellaneous_meta');
    $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
    $attribute->getFrontendLabel();
}
```

**block file**

```
<?php
namespace Test\Meta\Block;
class Meta extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{    
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;
        
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,        
        array $data = []
    )
    {    
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;    
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    
    public function getProductCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('miscellaneous_meta');
        
        return $collection;
    }
}
?>
```

but this is not working!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to add custom meta tag only on product page :

Create:

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="custom_meta" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/custom_meta.phtml" />
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Create phtml at:

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/custom_meta.phtml

```
<meta property="og:custom" content="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->stripTags($block->getProduct()->getMiscellaneousMeta()) ?>" />
```

**Note:**

- If you add phtml in `default_head_blocks.xml` it will render on all page and we only need for product page so use `catalog_product_view.xml`
- No need of custom block, we can use default `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View` block and can get product
- You can add as many meta tag you want in this phtml!

Comment: its still not coming as other meta tag and i want it to be displayed at top near meta title like this <meta name="meta-miscellaneous" content="misc conetnt"/>

Comment: it will add meta tag in head tag, you can use `after` or `before` to move content

Comment: i was trying it like this but its not working <referenceBlock name="head.additional" before="meta.title">

Comment: `after` and `before` can not be work with refrenceblock, you need to add with custom block we added

Comment: i need to put this reference block inside a referececontainter

Comment: simply the best ans thanks

Answer (score 0):

You do not think you need to add phtml here. You can manage from the plugin.

Create after plugin on `\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View::prepareAndRender`
add your custom meta info.

**here the plugin class**

```
<?php

namespace Devbera\Test\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;

class View
{
    /**
     * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $productRepository;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config
     */
    private $config;

    public function __construct(
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config $config
    )
    {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    public function FunctionName($productId = false)
    {
        if (!$productId) {
            return false;
        }

        try {
            $product = $this->productRepository
                ->getById(
                    $productId,
                    false,
                    $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()
                );
            $attribute = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('miscellaneous_meta');
            $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
            $value = $attribute->getFrontendLabel();
            $this->config->setMetadata('miscellaneous_meta', $value);
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function afterPrepareAndRender(
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View $subject,
        $result,
        $productId,
        $resultPage,
        $params = null,
        $controller
    )
    {
        if ($result instanceof \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View) {
            $this->addMetaData($productId);
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

**Note that code is not tested. It is given based idea.**